# How do I test and invalidate points close to the image border?

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing

I have the indices of several points of interest in a 3d image

`PIdx = [864, 865,866,867,868,869,870,871,872,873,874,2068,2079,3327];`

I am to perform certain operations at each of these points – one of which will involve finding the `east, west, north, south, top and bottom directions` from the points.

However, this operation results in error **“Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals”** and I realize this is because some of the `PIdx` are close to the border of the image in which case finding one or more of the specified directions will result in a negative index.

In order to resolve this, I am trying to invalidate any `PIdx` that is close to the border.
 **“edgeVectors”** is a `70644x3 cell array` from which the indices `PIdx` were gotten from. The corresponding elements of `PIdx` in `“edgeVectors”` are:

```
edgeVectors = ['A-' NaN NaN NaN NaN 'B+'
               'A-' NaN NaN NaN NaN 'B+'
               'A-' NaN NaN NaN NaN 'B+'
               'A-' NaN NaN NaN NaN 'B+'
               'A-' NaN NaN NaN NaN 'B+'
               'A-' NaN NaN NaN NaN 'B+'
               'A-' NaN NaN NaN NaN 'B+'
               'A-' NaN NaN NaN NaN 'B+'
               'A-' NaN NaN NaN NaN 'B+'
               'A-' NaN NaN NaN NaN 'B+'
               'A-' NaN NaN NaN NaN 'B+'
               'A-' NaN NaN 'B+' NaN NaN
               'B+' NaN 'A+' NaN NaN NaN
               'B-' NaN NaN NaN NaN 'A+'];
```

Equation for finding directions are as follows:

```
North  = PIdx + nx;
South  = PIdx – nx;
East   = Pidx + 1;
West   = PIdx – 1;
Top    = PIdx +  ( ny*(2*nx - 1) - nx + (nx*ny) );
Bottom = Pidx - ( ny*(2*nx - 1) - nx + (nx*ny) );
```

Where:

```
nx = ImagesizeX-1;
ny = ImagesizeY-1;
nx=29; ny=29
```

**To test for bottom direction at the border for instance I have:**

```
for ii = 1: numel(PIdx) 
    if sign( PIdx(ii,:) - ( ny*(2*nx - 1) - nx + (nx*ny) ) ) == -1
        edgeVectors(ii, :) = {NaN};     %invalidate PIdx    
    end
end
```

**for PIdx(1)**,

bottom = 864 – 2465 = -1601

sign(-1601) = -1

hence, I would expect the code above to return

```
edgeVectors =  NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

This however does not happen.

Any ideas what I am getting wrong here? Or is there any suggestions/reference on how I could achieve this? Many thanks.

Comment: I didn't read all of this, but if you want to check if a pixel that `PIdx` is referring to, is close to the border, you just need to check if the elements of `ind2sub(size(image),PIdx(i))` are either close so 0 or close to the width/heigth of the image.

Comment: An easier way is to pad your image with a new border containing values that won't affect your calculations.

Comment: Thank you all for your advise. I guess i figured out the way to go. What i did was to increase the size of the image relative to the resolution. Note that i am dealing with a synthetic image and therefore for real images this will mean padding as suggested by @beaker.